# Github Actions pm2: command not found

Tags: github-actions, pm2, github-actions-runners

I am trying to auto-deploy the project and npm commands run perfectly but when it goes to a line where pm2 restarts the specific projects, then actions fails.

GitHub Actions Error:

[GitHub Actions Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdjxl.png)

GitHub Action .yml file content:

[yml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiXvP.png)

Comment: try pm2 -f start app.js on application start

Comment: @LumbusterTick I am trying to do this using github actions .yml file. And getting error pm2: command not found. I have tried everything. Please take a look at the screenshots attahced.

Comment: The only reason its not found is because pm2 was not installed either when configuring the instance or in app spec yaml

Answer (score 21):

**NOTE: This solution is applicable only when you are using an NVM to manage node.js versions**

The issue is because of the missing symbolic link for the node and the pm2, here are the commands that you can use to create a symbolic link:

```
sudo ln -s "$NVM_DIR/versions/node/$(nvm version)/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/node"

sudo ln -s "$NVM_DIR/versions/node/$(nvm version)/bin/npm" "/usr/local/bin/npm"

sudo ln -s "$NVM_DIR/versions/node/$(nvm version)/bin/pm2" "/usr/local/bin/pm2"
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because pm2 is not linked, for linking

Access your server via ssh, after that get the path of pm2 by

```
whereis pm2
```

You will get the output of your path like
pm2: /home/abhimanyu/.nvm/versions/node/v18.12.1/bin/pm2

[image]

**Copy the path**

**link your path now**

```
sudo ln -s "$NVM_DIR/versions/node/v18.12.1/bin/pm2" "/usr/local/bin/pm2"
```

***versions/node/v18.12.1/bin/pm2 is my path your path may be diffrent***

Comment: Thanks, I can confirm this solution works and this is needed for those who installed pm2 as non-root or non-sudo users.

Answer (score 2):

lo que pasa es que seguro instalaste todo por NVM lo cual no esta mal, pero para que puedas utilizar pm2 dentro del action de github, lo que tienes que realizar es.

sudo ln -s "$NVM_DIR/versions/node/$(nvm version)/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/node"

sudo ln -s "$NVM_DIR/versions/node/$(nvm version)/bin/npm" "/usr/local/bin/npm"

sudo ln -s "$NVM_DIR/versions/node/$(nvm version)/bin/pm2" "/usr/local/bin/pm2"

despues de la intalacion para que asi puedas utilizar con sudo el pm2 y de esa forma te funcionara sin problemas

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I run into the same issue.
So basically, `pm2` is not installed. I found it a bit strange as in my VPS, the pm2 is installed and is running perfectly.
The way I got around with it was to create a bash script in the root directory of my project: `pm2_runner.sh`, within this file I added:

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! type pm2 > /dev/null
then
    sudo npm install -g pm2 && pm2 start ./app.js --name my_project_name
else
    pm2 restart my_project_name
fi
```

Then in my .yml file inside `.github/workflow/`, instead of writing:

```
- run: pm2 restart my_project_name
```

I added:

```
- run: chmod +x ./pm2_runner.sh
- run: bash ./pm2_runner.sh
```

It installed `pm2` globally without requesting sudo passord since sudo in github actions runs using passwordless.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding pm2 to the `$GITHUB_PATH`

First, create a test github action to log the user configured for using the runner

```
- run: |
  echo $USER
  echo $PATH
```

Login to your server as the user configured for the runner and run this command

```bash
which pm2
```

Copy the output and add it to your github action

```
- name: Add directory to PATH
  run: echo "/path/to/.nvm/versions/node/v14.21.3/bin" >> $GITHUB_PATH
```

[Shown here in the github docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#adding-a-system-path)