# pm2: command not found

Tags: deployment, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am implementing CI CD piplines through github actions workflow . Here is the content of the file of my workflow:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - features/testing-ci-cd
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Getting latest code
        run:  git pull origin features/testing-ci-cd
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: Build
        run: npm run build
      - name: Service restart
        run: pm2 restart 2
```

All the steps are working fine even build is generating but when I restart the process it's giving the error
/home/runner/work/_temp/1fd78e6d-63b3-4bba-bce1-7682aa48d840.sh: line 5: pm2: command not found

I am using gitHub runners
I have tries with multiple actions but not working trie with installing pm2 globally , adding pm2 path etc
Any workaround ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Github Actions pm2: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69644460/github-actions-pm2-command-not-found)

Comment: Already tried these but not working

Comment: Please include what you have tried along with its outcome. Thanks!